# how to audit users with old password versions

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I must set

```
SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=12a
```

on all of my database servers.

How can I check if clients still use old authentication protocols?

I know I can check `DBA_USERS` for old password versions. However, how can check that user *actually* uses old password version? listener.log? Audit trail?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56531594/836215

```
SQL> select username, PASSWORD_VERSIONS from dba_users;

USERNAME                       PASSWORD_VERSIONS
------------------------------ -----------------
SYS                            10G 11G 12C
```

This will tell you is which formats are passwords stored.
Also this article describes password formats in [detail](https://www.trustwave.com/en-us/resources/blogs/spiderlabs-blog/changes-in-oracle-database-12c-password-hashes/).

There is also a view `V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO` which tells you which version/kind of client SW is used by application. If this view does not contain any reliable information, your client uses some very old JDBC drivers. What you have to care about is the version of client driver.

PS: This view will also tell you whether client negotiated any encryption for session connection.

Answer (score 2):

In order to meet the minimum protocol requirement for your `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER` value, the user would have to have set their password already using that sqlnet protocol version. If they have not, they will not be able to authenticate to the database - even if they have a valid password under an older protocol - and their client will return an error about not finding a matching authentication protocol. In that case, their password would need to be reset by the DBA using the newer protocol before they could connect.

Under no circumstances will the database allow an older protocol than the one specified in sqlnet.ora to be used, so there's nothing to audit, per se. All older protocol authentication requests are simply rejected.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you! If a user has no 12C in his password versions, he won't be able to login and vice versa. The last part for some reason was not clear for me.